Is it reasonable to use information criteria (like AIC) to compare ARIMA models fit to transformed data with different Box-Cox lambdas?
I am using the auto.arima function from the forecast package in R.
I have the following 2 model fits
> (ar_fit_0 <- auto.arima(series_data, lambda = 0, max.d = 0))
Series: series_data 
ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean 
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     mean
      1.2472  -0.2572  -0.8259  14.9760
s.e.  0.0579   0.0551   0.0394   0.2315

sigma^2 = 0.1508:  log likelihood = -341.64
AIC=693.27   AICc=693.36   BIC=716.2

> (ar_fit_auto <- auto.arima(series_data, lambda = "auto", max.d = 0))
Series: series_data 
ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean 
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0.1369332 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     mean
      1.2522  -0.2620  -0.8260  49.6173
s.e.  0.0582   0.0554   0.0396   1.8434

sigma^2 = 9.216:  log likelihood = -1832.6
AIC=3675.21   AICc=3675.29   BIC=3698.14

The only difference between the 2 is the second one uses automatic Box-Cox lambda selection
The automatic lambda selection results in a higher AIC. But I am a bit sceptical of using the likelihood related metrics as  in these cases. The data has been transformed in different ways and I suspect the fitting procedure only sees the transformed data, so doesn't "know" a transformation has taken place.

These can be viewed as different models, so one can compare the likelihoods. Using AIC or BIC is unnecessary, since the number of parameters is the same, so that the penalty term doesn't change.

@RogerV. your answer would suggest that the automatic lambda selection in auto.arima is flawed, since choosing by likelihood results in a very different value. Would you agree?

It depends on whether the likelihood reported by auto.arima correctly includes the Jacobian correction, e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261380/how-do-i-get-the-box-cox-log-likelihood-using-the-jacobian
